# How to get random id documents in a collection and generate the random id in StreamBuilder flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

i try to generate the random id in Stream Builder by flutter In the end, random posts are generated every time the user enters the application and are changed automatically every time the user Another entry .

As an example of what I want to do is posts

Facebook -
Instagram -
Tik Tok -
Twitter .

They all generate random posts

I hope I made clear the meaning of my question.

**that is my code**

```
class ContainersPublicScreen extends StatefulWidget {
 final categoryText;
 final categoryName;
 final categoryId;
 final userLanguage;

 const ContainersPublicScreen(
     {Key? key,
     required this.categoryText,
     required this.categoryName,
     required this.categoryId,
     required this.userLanguage})
     : super(key: key);

 @override
 State<ContainersPublicScreen> createState() => _ContainersPublicScreenState();
}

class _ContainersPublicScreenState extends State<ContainersPublicScreen> {
 bool isLoading = false;
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return isLoading
       ? circularProgress(context)
       : Container(
           color: borderCardColor,
           height: 300,
           child: Padding(
             padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
             child: Column(children: [
               SizedBox(
                 height: 20,
                 child: Row(
                   children: [
                     Expanded(
                       child: Text(
                         widget.categoryText,
                         style: const TextStyle(
                             color: primaryColor,
                             fontSize: 15,
                             fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                       ),
                     ),
                     InkWell(
                       onTap: () {
                         Navigator.of(context).push(
                           MaterialPageRoute(
                             builder: (_) => PublicScreen(
                               categoryText:
                                   widget.categoryText,
                               categoryId:
                                   widget.categoryId,
                               categoryName:
                                   widget.categoryName,
                              userLanguage:
                                   widget.userLanguage,
                             ),
                           ),
                         );
                       },
                       child: Text(
                         'moor'.tr,
                         style: const TextStyle(
                             color: primaryColor,
                             fontSize: 15,
                             fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                       ),
                     ),
                   ],
                 ),
               ),
               const SizedBox(
                 height: 5.0,
               ),
               SizedBox(
                 height: 255.0,
                 child: StreamBuilder(
                   stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                       .collection('publicPost')
                       .where(
                         'languageId',
                         isEqualTo: widget.userLanguage,
                       )
                       .where(
                         'categoryId',
                         isEqualTo: widget.categoryId,
                       )
                       .where(
                         'categoryName',
                         isEqualTo: widget.categoryName,
                       )
                       .snapshots(),
                   builder: (context,
                       AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>
                           snapshot) {
                     if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data!.docs.isNotEmpty) {
                       return ListView.separated(
                         scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                         separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                           return const VerticalDivider();
                         },
                         itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                         itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => SizedBox(
                           height: 290,
                           child: PublicContainersCard(
                             snap: snapshot.data!.docs[index].data(),
                           ),
                         ),
                       );
                     } else if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                         ConnectionState.waiting) {
                       return circularProgress(context);
                     } else {
                       return Center(
                         child: Column(
                           crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                           mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                           children: [
                             const Icon(
                               Icons.hourglass_empty,
                               color: primaryColor,
                             ),
                             const SizedBox(
                               height: 4,
                             ),
                             Text(
                               'noCategory'.tr,
                               style: const TextStyle(
                                 color: primaryColor,
                                 fontSize: 15,
                                 fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                               ),
                             ),
                           ],
                         ),
                       );
                     }
                   },
                 ),
               )
             ]),
           ),
         );
 }
}
```

Really grateful for the help or even the attempt to help from the programmers' family .

I also wish it were possible to develop the generation of posts, provided that it was related to the user’s search words or visits within the application, and that it be random .

If this matter is currently advanced, it is sufficient for it to be just random .

**In any case**

I am grateful for the help from the family of programmers stack over flow .